# How to memoize useSelector value so that re render is prevented on any state change in the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am using callback to memoize part of component which uses useSelector value. But another state variable is changing withing the component as I am taking input, which is triggering another re render of comp, thereby useselector is getting called again and re rendering the part where I have used useCallback as selector value  is there as a dependency.
How can I memorize useSelector value so that any state change change within the component does not trigger selector update unless dispatch gets called somewhere and updates the state.

```
const chat = useSelector((state: any) => state.user.rooms[index]) 
const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
```

chat is the selector value and message is the state for input tag.

```
const Component = useCallback(() => {
    return (
      <div className="h-[75%] bg-yellow-200 relative overflow-y-scroll flex  flex-col">
        {chat?.messages.map((message: any, index: number) => {
          console.log(message.sentBy._id, userId);
          let sentByme = message.sentBy._id === userId;
          return (
            <div className={"w-[50%] min-h-[20%]  border-4  rounded-3xl "}>
              <p>{message.text}</p>
              <p>
                {message.timeStamp} : {sentByme ? "me" : message.sentBy.name}
              </p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }, [chat]);
```

I decided to set aside chat selector value inside of useCallback to prevent re render on input state change ie "message"
but re rendering is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Components rerender as a whole, and per default all their children will re-render after that as well. If you want a part of your component not to rerender, you need to split that into two components and render them side-by-side or wrap the child component in React.memo.

Selectors will be executed on each render and also on every Redux dispatch - if that is a performance problem at some point, look into memoized selectors. https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data

In your case the selector itself is not a performance problem at all though.

Comment: i just need to memoize chats so that it does not rerender upon any other state change in the component. also implemented React.memo to convert rendering chats to HOC but still not working.

Comment: You might have a very wrong model on when and how a React component renders (and what rendering actually means). I would suggest you give https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/ a read.

Comment: thank you .. i fixed it by using react.memo.. and the blog is giving me more insights